# Find ordered vector in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, vector, numpy

I need to find a vector in a numpy.array. 
For example, I have a np.array named e and I want to find the vector [1, 2] in e (meaning that I would like to have the index of the vector inside the matrix) but apparently my programm see the vector even when is not present:

[image]

The code I use to built e in the following:

```
import numpy as np
faces = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,2,1],[6,7,3,2],[7,8,4,3],[8,5,1,4],[8,7,6,5]])
e = np.zeros([6,4,2])
for k in range(len(faces)):
    a = [faces[k][0], faces[k][1]]
    b = [faces[k][1], faces[k][2]] 
    c = [faces[k][2], faces[k][3]]
    d = [faces[k][3], faces[k][0]]
    e[k] = np.array([a,b,c,d])
 print('e: %s' %e)
```

any clue how to solve this?

Comment: Including code was helpful. The image is superfluous; just include the stuff you tried in text form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
e[np.all((e-np.array([1,2]))==0, axis=2)]
```

Brief explanation. `e-np.array([1,2])` returns `[0,0]` where it is `[1,2]` in array `e`. `np.all(..., axis=2` returns the Boolean array: `True` if `[0,0]` `False` otherwise (so things such as `[1,1]` will become False). Finally, just slice it from e.

To get the index of `[1,2]`'s (there may be multiple sub vector `[1,2]`):

```
np.argwhere(np.all((e-array([1,2]))==0, axis=2))
```

Comment: it works exactly as I needed! Just one note: I get the warning that argwhere is an undefined name (I'm using python 2.7.5) I may need to import some packet but that's of course not a problem, thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you didn't have `from numpy import *` it will need to be `np.argwhere`. Edited.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use Python `in` with numpy arrays.

There are 6 x 4 pairs in `e`.

```
In [32]: e.shape
Out[32]: (6, 4, 2)
```

You are looking an element that matches both (i.e., `all()`) entries in the pair `[1, 2]`.

```
In [33]: (e == np.array([1, 2])).all(-1)
Out[33]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

The `-1` in `all(-1)` refers the last dimension in the array, the part of the shape that constitutes pairs. Using -1 is probably more general than using 2, which would also work in this case.

It found the right match -- the only `True` value. You can see the shape of this result makes sense.

```
In [34]: (e == np.array([1, 2])).all(-1).shape
Out[34]: (6, 4)
```

To get the **index of the first match** you could do

```
x, y = (e == np.array([1, 2])).all(-1).argmax(1).argmax(), (e == np.array([1, 2])).all(-1).argmax(0).argmax()
```

but using `np.argwhere` suggested in CT Zhu's answer is definitely better.

Comment: but then how can I take-have-print the index of the True value? Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: when I'm looking for a different vector [1,4] it don't give the correct result: x = (e == np.array([1, 4])).all(-1).argmin(1).argmax()
y = (e == np.array([1, 4])).all(-1).argmin(0).argmax() return x=0, y=0..why??

Comment: My mistake. See edited answer. I should be ``argmax`` in every case (never ``argmin``). On a boolean array, ``argmax`` means "index of the first ``True`` value." For example, ``(e == np.array([1, 4])).all(-1).argmax(0).argmax()``
 gives 2, properly.

Comment: "Don't use Python `in` with numpy arrays". Why do you state this?

Comment: Because it does not take advantage of vectorization and is therefore slow.

Comment: `(e == np.array([1, 2])).all(-1)` works like a charm :))

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following trick to view your vectors as single items of `np.void` dtype:

```
e = np.ascontiguousarray(e)
dt = np.dtype((np.void, e.dtype.itemsize * e.shape[-1]))
e_view = e.view(dt)
search = np.array([1, 2], dtype=e.dtype).view(dt)
```

You can now extract the positions with `np.in1d`:

```
mask = np.in1d(e_view, search)
indices = np.unravel_index(np.where(mask), e.shape[:-1])

>>> indices
(array([[0]], dtype=int64), array([[0]], dtype=int64))
```

The return arrays is a tuple with the rows and columns of the occurrences of `search`, in this case there is only one, at `(0, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

This will print out all the indices of e and whether it is equal to [1,2].  If you wanted to return the indices, instead of printing them, you could add `(num, num2)` to another list, and that would give you all the locations of `[1,2]`.  Would need to be extended to work with arrays of more levels.

```
for num, item in enumerate(e):
    for num2, item2 in enumerate(item):                                    
        print ('e[{i}][{j}]: {truth}'.format(i=num, 
                                             j=num2, 
                                             truth = (item2 == [1,2]).all()))
```

Output:

```
e[0][0]: True                                                                                                          
e[0][1]: False                                                                                                         
e[0][2]: False                                                                                                         
e[0][3]: False                                                                                                         
e[1][0]: False                                                                                                         
e[1][1]: False                                                                                                         
e[1][2]: False                                                                                                         
e[1][3]: False                                                                                                         
e[2][0]: False                                                                                                         
e[2][1]: False                                                                                                         
e[2][2]: False                                                                                                         
e[2][3]: False                                                                                                         
e[3][0]: False                                                                                                         
e[3][1]: False                                                                                                         
e[3][2]: False                                                                                                         
e[3][3]: False                                                                                                         
e[4][0]: False                                                                                                         
e[4][1]: False                                                                                                         
e[4][2]: False                                                                                                         
e[4][3]: False                                                                                                         
e[5][0]: False                                                                                                         
e[5][1]: False                                                                                                         
e[5][2]: False                                                                                                         
e[5][3]: False
```

Comment: and if I wanted to print the element after the one that match? (or to save it into a variable)

Comment: not sure I quite get the question, but you could use this:

https://gist.github.com/garth5689/6870607  Basically, just add an item to try and find the next element, and add it to the print string.  It will print None on `IndexErrors`.

Comment: The benefit of using numpy is the first place is to avoid slow Python loops.